# UISearchController iOS 11 not in navigation bar busted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have an app in production. On iPad, the layout is 2 table views on one layout. There is a search bar for the left hand table view. In iOS 9/10 this worked fine- the search bar, when expanded, simply appeared in the table view. In iOS 11, the same code will make the search bar expand out of the table view and attach to the nav bar area at the top of the screen.

If I change the presentation context of the search controller, then in iOS 11 it is completely broken and does not work.

```
self.definesPresentationContext = YES; //YES PRESENTS SEARCH BAR IN TABLE VIEW
```

I have created a demo project to simplify the example, this is directly Apple's table demo with the table view made as not full screen. The presentation context can be set to either the table view or not, and the search bar scope buttons can be easily added or not.

In the demo, the search controller, when presented inside of the table view, can be tapped in order to start a search, but is completely unresponsive to any taps - the cancel button, the X to clear text, trying to move the cursor. Keyboard text entry works and it will correctly filter the items. But then you're stuck and can't exit.

Here's a link to the demo project. Am I missing something or is this an Apple bug? Majority of code in *APLMainTableViewController.m*.

[DOWNLOAD CODE EXAMPLE at this link](http://www.paveglio.com/postimages/uisearchcontroller/searchcontrollerproblems-ios11.zip)

Full app image:

[image: Image of full app UI]

Correctly working search in iOS 10:

[image: Example of iOS 10 correct table search bar]

Demo project screenshot with bad search controller:

[image: iOS 11 bad search controller in table frame]

Comment: For what it's worth, I went back to Apple's demo, did what I presumed you did (put the view controller with the table view as an embedded view on a new main view controller) and (a) was not able to reproduce your "Cancel" problem; but (b) have been able to reproduce the `scopeButtonTitles` problem.

Comment: OK that's interesting, I'll have another stab at it. Or PM me on twitter and I'll give you my email if you could send your version to me. Thanks.

Comment: See my rendition at https://github.com/robertmryan/TableSearchwithUISearchController/tree/embedded-view-iPad. This shows that the "cancel" button works fine (when I used your project I did see that "cancel" wasn't working, but I haven't reverse engineered what you did that caused that to happen).